# LINQ Join/Update List of Objects from Database

Tags: c#, linq, join

This issue is a new one to me in LINQ. And maybe I'm going about this wrong.

What I have is a list of objects in memory, which could number up to 100k, and I need to find in my database which objects represent an existing customer.

This search needs to be done across multiple object properties and all I have to go on are the name and address of the person - no unique identifier since this data comes from an outside source.

Is it possible to join my generic of objects against my database context and then update the generic objects, with data from the context, based on whether they are found in the join?

I thought I was getting close to the join working with the below code.  And I think the join works .. maybe.  But I can't even seem to loop through the records.

```
public void FindCustomerMatches(List<DocumentLine> lines)
{
  IQueryable<DocumentLine> results = null;
  var linesQuery = lines.AsQueryable();

  using (var customerContext = new Entities())
  {
    customerContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    var dbCustomerQuery = customerContext.customers.Where(c => !c.customernumber.StartsWith("D"));

    results = from c in dbCustomerQuery
              from l in linesQuery
              where c.firstname1 == l.CustomerFirstName
              && c.lastname1 == l.CustomerLastName
              && c.street_address1.Contains(l.CustomerAddress)
              && c.city == l.CustomerCity
              && c.state == l.CustomerState
              && c.zip == l.CustomerZip
              select l;

      foreach (var result in results)
      {
          // Do something with each record here, like update it.
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a Customer class?  If there is a DocumentLine.Customer and Customer class has a constructor that can load a record from customerContext, you can do a groupby on DocumentLines where customers start with 'D' and AddRange( dbCustomerQuery) where the same parameters apply.

Comment: There is a customer class but unfortunately its more of a DTO and isn't supposed to know how to load data from the database itself.  Otherwise, I see what you mean and that could work.

Comment: hmm ... either both lists need to join into the same dto or you are going to have to do two searches.  Perhaps its not vital to be stuck on doing everything in a single process or perhaps use the dto to normalize the data between DocumentLine and dbCustomQuery.  The issue i see is that you want to join data from DocumentLine with data coming from an anonymous type.

Comment: Yep I finally got the anonymous type issue resolved.  I think I may be stuck with uploading this data to the database server for processing.  It just takes too long in LINQ (in this situation).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have two collections: a local collection of `DocumentLines` in variable `lines`, and a collection of `Customers` in a `customerContext.Customers`, probably in a database management system.

Every `DocumentLine` contains several properties that can also be found in a `Customer`. Alas you didn't say whether all `DocumentLine` properties can be found in a `Customer`.

From `lines` (the local collection of `DocumentLines`) you only want to keep only those `DocumentLines` of which there is at least one `Customer` in your queryable collection of `Customers` that match all these properties.

So the result is a sequence of `DocumentLines`, a sub-collection of `lines`.

The problem is that you don't want to query a sub-collection of the database table `Customers`, but you want a sub-collection of your local `lines`.

Using `AsQueryable` doesn't transport your `lines` to your DBMS. I doubt whether the  query you defined will be performed by the DBMS. I suspect that all `Customers` will be transported to your local process to perform the query.

If all properties of a `DocumentLine` are in a `Customer` then it is possible to *extract* the `DocumentLines` properties from every `Customer` and use `Queryable.Contains` to keep only those extracted `DocumentLines` that are in your `lines`:

```
IQueryable<DocumentLine> customerDocumentLines = dbContext.Customers
    .Select(customer => new DocumentLine()
    {
         FirstName = customer.FirstName,
         LastName = customer.LastName,
         ...
         // etc, fill all DocumentLine properties
    });
```

Note: the query is not executed yet! No communication with the DBMS is performed

Your requested result are all customerDocumentLines that are contained in `lines`, removing the duplicates.

```
var result = customerDocumentLines        // extract the document lines from all Customers
    .Distinct                             // remove duplicates
    .Where(line => lines.Contains(line)); // keep only those lines that are in lines
```

This won't work if you can't extract a complete `DocumentLine` from a `Customer`. If `lines` contains duplicates, the result won't show these duplicates.

If you can't extract all properties from a `DocumentLine` you'll have to move the values to check to local memory:

```
var valuesToCompare = dbContext.Customers
    .Select(customer => new
    {
        FirstName = customer.FirstName,
        LastName = customer.LastName,
        ...
        // etc, fill all values you need to check
    })
    .Distinct()                // remove duplicates
    .AsEnumerable();           // make it IEnumerable,
                               // = efficiently move to local memory
```

Now you can use `Enumerable.Contains` to get the subset of lines. You'll need to compare by value, not by reference. Luckily anonymous types compare for equality by value

```
var result = lines

    // extract the values to compare
    .Select(line => new
    {
        Line = line,
        ValuesToCompare = new
        {
            FirstName = customer.FirstName,
            LastName = customer.LastName,
            ...
        })
    })

    // keep only those lines that match valuesToCheck
    .Where(line => valuesToCheck.Contains(line.ValuesToCompare));
```